# ReSharper Adjust/Refactor Namespaces not respecting folders with spaces in them

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, resharper

I'm trying to refactor the namespaces in my project with ReSharper 8.2. I'm using the `Refactor->Adjust Namespaces` option, which is really awesome, but it doesn't seem to work when the folders in the project have spaces. With this project structure (in VS):

```
Project
   |
   |-Some Folder
       |
       |-ASubFolder
          |
          |-CodeFile.cs
```

My new namespace in `CodeFile.cs` will be `Project.ASubFolder`, whereas if I have this structure

```
Project
   |
   |-SomeFolder
       |
       |-ASubFolder
          |
          |-CodeFile.cs
```

The namespace is renamed appropriately to `Project.SomeFolder.ASubFolder`. I have checked that the `Namespace provider` property is set on all the folders. How do I force R# to use folders with spaces in them when refactoring?

Edit: My expected output in the first scenario is `Project.SomeFolder.ASubFolder`. I want ReSharper to just remove the space.

Comment: I would actually expect `Project.Some_Folder.ASubFolder`, since that's the default namespace used in Visual Studio when you add a new item to the folder.

Comment: Yeah even that would be valid. Just removing the name all together is not expected behaviour IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have spaces in a namespace (i.e. `Project.Some Folder.ASubFolder` would not be valid).

So whatever ReSharper did in this situation (such as ignoring the spaces), you'd end up with a mismatch between your folder structure and your namespaces. Ignoring the folder name completely if it contains spaces seems as reasonable as any other solution.

Having spaces in folder names is just going to cause you problems with other tools in future so is best avoided if you can.

Comment: I'm aware that I can't have spaces in a namespace. My expectation for the output is `Project.SomeFolder.ASubFolder` for both the top and bottom scenarios. I want R# to just remove the space when refactoring.

Comment: So apparently your expectation of this undefined behaviour differs from that of the designers of R#.

Comment: That's why I asked the question. Actually that's why most people ask questions: "This is happening, how do I fix it?".

Answer (score 2):

The work-around my team ended up using for this problem was to replace spaces in the folder names with underscores.

Because the Visual Studio convention is to use underscores in namespaces where spaces exist in folders, any class which was already using the correct namespace would not have to change.  Because the spaces were gone, we were free to run ReSharper's Fix Namespaces to achieve the same result for the remaining classes.